# Deserialize from string instead TextReader

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I want to change my code from:

```
string path = @"c:\Directory\test.xml";
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Car));

TextReader r = new StreamReader(path);

Car car = (Car)s.Deserialize(r);
r.Close();
```

into code that would convert an XML to a string, and then convert string to the object Car.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 287, accepted):

```
public static string XmlSerializeToString(this object objectInstance)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(objectInstance.GetType());
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    using (TextWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, objectInstance);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}

public static T XmlDeserializeFromString<T>(this string objectData)
{
    return (T)XmlDeserializeFromString(objectData, typeof(T));
}

public static object XmlDeserializeFromString(this string objectData, Type type)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
    object result;

    using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(objectData))
    {
        result = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }

    return result;
}
```

To use it:

```
//Make XML
var settings = new ObjectCustomerSettings();
var xmlString = settings.XmlSerializeToString();

//Make Object
var settings = xmlString.XmlDeserializeFromString<ObjectCustomerSettings>();
```

Comment: Better:

public static T XmlDeserializeFromString<T>(string objectData)
{
    return (T)XmlDeserializeFromString(objectData, typeof(T));
}

Comment: can I remove "this" from 

public static string XmlSerializeToString(this object objectInstance)

??

Comment: You could remove 'this', but then the method is not an extension method anymore. By making the method an extension method, this is possible:

string s = "blah!";
string xml = s.XmlSerializeToString();

note: be sure to reference the namespace of the static class that holds the extension methods in your usings, or the extension methods will not work!

The only reason for using 'this' is to make it an extension method, it's completely safe to remove it.

Comment: You are missing the "this". in your 2nd method to get it to show as an extention.

`public static T XmlDeserializeFromString<T>(this string objectData) 
{
            return (T)XmlDeserializeFromString(objectData, typeof(T)); 
}`
I am going to edit the main post.

Answer (score 94):

If you have the XML stored inside a string variable you could use a [StringReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.aspx):

```
var xml = @"<car/>";
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Car));
using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    var car = (Car)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Comment: using(var reader = new StringReader(xml))
                return (Car)new XmlSerializer(typeof(Car)).Deserialize(reader);

Answer (score 17):

1-liner, takes a XML string `text` and `YourType` as the expected object type. not very different from other answers, just compressed to 1 line:

```
var result =  (YourType)new XmlSerializer(typeof(YourType)).Deserialize(new StringReader(text));
```

Comment: I would close the StringReader after usage.

Answer (score 8):

```
static T DeserializeXml<T>(string sourceXML) where T : class
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    T result = null;

    using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(sourceXML))
    {
        result = (T) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Shamelessly copied from 
[Generic deserialization of an xml string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996876/generic-deserialization-of-an-xml-string)

```
    public static T DeserializeFromXmlString<T>(string xmlString)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
        {
            return (T) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
```