# How do i desrialize an xml from a string

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, xml-parsing, c#-3.0

Please i am trying to convert the result I got from my web service as a string and convert it to an object.

This is the string I'm getting from my service:

```
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <AccountStatementResponse xmlns="http://formalityzues.com/">
         <AccountStatementResult><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><ViewStatementResponse><TransactionItems><RefNumber>2</RefNumber><TransactionDate>31/05/2017</TransactionDate><ValueDate>31/05/2017</ValueDate><Amount>400</Amount><Narration>CHIEF ATTENDANT</Narration><TransactionType>CR</TransactionType><BalanceAfterTransaction>57003602.16</BalanceAfterTransaction></TransactionItems><TransactionItems><RefNumber>3</RefNumber><TransactionDate>31/05/2017</TransactionDate><ValueDate>31/05/2017</ValueDate><Amount>3800</Amount><Narration>HEAD QUATERS</Narration><TransactionType>CR</TransactionType><BalanceAfterTransaction>57007402.16</BalanceAfterTransaction></TransactionItems></ViewStatementResponse>]]></AccountStatementResult>
      </AccountStatementResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Please how do i go about it?

```
[XmlRoot("ViewStatementResponse")]
public class Model
{
    [XmlElement("OpeningBalance")]
    public string OpeningBalance { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ClosingBalance")]
    public string ClosingBalance { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("TransactionItems")]
    public List<TransactionDetails> TransactionItems { get; set; } 
}

public class TransactionDetails
{
    [XmlElement("RefNumber")]
    public string RefNumber { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("TransactionDate")]
    public string TransactionDate { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ValueDate")]
    public string ValueDate { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Amount")]
    public string Amount { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Narration")]
    public string Narration { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("TransactionType")]
    public string TransactionType { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("BalanceAfterTransaction")]
    public string BalanceAfterTransaction { get; set; }
}
```

i am using this but it is not returning error.
i am unable to do it. i am new to working on xml.please assist

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize from string instead TextReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347642/deserialize-from-string-instead-textreader)

Comment: How are you calling the server? The provided XML is a SOAP-response - are you using SOAP or do you fetch that data via GET/POST? Aside from that this should work with a default XmlSerializer - may show the code you already tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a starter the following does work to read your XML as given in the question:

```
var soap = XDocument.Parse(response); // response is the XML as given
var data = soap.Descendants("{http://formalityzues.com/}AccountStatementResult").First();
var reader = new StringReader(data.Value);
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Model));
var model = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as Model;
```

See the following fiddle for a working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fvYYqD